# How to make JSX elements not move with conditional rendering inside flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

In my React.js im using conditional rendering to display or not display some elements.

The problem I'm having is that since my Main element is a flexbox all elements move when new element is rendered.

Example image from my project:
[MainElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SBu5.png)

On the link, there are two pictures, 1st picture is when button is toggled to 'Learn' mode, and 2nd picture is image on 'Normal' mode.
On the bottom of the picture we can see that rendering the 'Record:' element shifts all middle elements upwards (since the CSS justify-content of flexbox is set to 'space-between').

main.css:

```
main {
font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
margin: 75px auto;
background-color: #29416E;
border: 3px solid #D9C241;
height: 650px;
width: 1100px;
max-width: 1300px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

}

Main.js:

```
                <div>
                <h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{points} points / {mistakes} mistakes</h3>
                {normalMode && <h4 className='main--textCenter'>Record: {pointsRecord ? pointsRecord : 0}</h4>}
            </div>
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is that when rendering new elements, elements stay on the same spot, and the conditional element pops up in its designated place without moving any other elements.

Question I'm having is how to solve this issue? Should I avoid flex when conditional rendering, or is there a way to bypass this by rendering empty placeholder objects?

Answer (score 0):

From my own understanding, everything is working as it should. Since, please take note, there is conditional rendering, some blocks of HTML are literally not there if that condition is not met.

That's why I said it's working as it should, your flexbox and CSS, in general, are working fine.

**My suggestion**

Actually, this has been a hint from the placeholder elements thing you mentioned in your post.

Since you know for a fact that you want to display an element based on a condition ie normal mode set to `true` you could display another element while this condition is not met ie normal mode set to `false`.

I would suggest more CSS for the element you should display if the normal mode is set to `false`.

This would interchange these elements based on the condition that has been or is currently matched.

I hope I leave you in good shape.

Happy Hacking!!!